# Xamarin Forms - Button Margin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following Xaml:

```
<Grid Padding="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ContentView Grid.Column="0">
          <Button Text="SomeText" 
                  BorderRadius="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                  BorderWidth="0"
                  BackgroundColor="Red"
                  TextColor="White"
                  ></Button>
        </ContentView>
        <ContentView Grid.Column="0">
          <Button Text="SomeText" 
                  BorderRadius="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                  BorderWidth="0"
                  BackgroundColor="Blue
                  TextColor="White"
                  ></Button>
        </ContentView>
        <ContentView Grid.Column="0">
          <Button Text="SomeText" 
                  BorderRadius="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                  BorderWidth="0"
                  BackgroundColor="Green
                  TextColor="White"
                  ></Button>
        </ContentView>
      </Grid>
```

When this renders, there is a gap between each of the buttons. I want the buttons to touch. I can't see any padding or margin set anywhere though?

Comment: Is the ContentVIew on each necessary? If I remember right it has a Padding set by default. Or how about Button, is there a default template it's using giving it Margin? Also you don't need to have Grid.* declarations on child elements, just their parents.

Comment: Grid objects have a `RowSpacing` and `ColumnSpacing` property which you can set to cero;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<Grid Padding="0" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
```

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="ButtonPaddingTest.ButtonPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid Padding="0" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" >
          <Button Text="SomeText" 
                  BorderRadius="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                  BorderWidth="0"
                  BackgroundColor="Red"
                  TextColor="White"
                  ></Button>
        </ContentView>
        <ContentView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" >
          <Button Text="SomeText" 
                  BorderRadius="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                  BorderWidth="0"
                  BackgroundColor="Blue"
                  TextColor="White"
                  ></Button>
        </ContentView>
        <ContentView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" >
          <Button Text="SomeText" 
                  BorderRadius="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                  BorderWidth="0"
                  BackgroundColor="Green"
                  TextColor="White"
                  ></Button>
        </ContentView>
      </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: This worked thank you. Can't believe I couldn't find that info myself!